# Python Enum AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'StrEnum'

Tags: python, class, enums

I am working on Windows 11, using Python 3.11; I'm working on the following code snippet, which comes from from the Python docs on [enum.StrEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum)

```py
import enum
from enum import StrEnum


class Build(StrEnum):
    DEBUG = enum.auto()
    OPTIMIZED = enum.auto()

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        value = value.lower()
        for member in cls:
            if member.value == value:
                return member
        return None

print(Build.DEBUG.value)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'StrEnum' from 'enum'`. I made the following changes:

```py
import enum

class Build(enum.StrEnum):  # <--change made here
    DEBUG = enum.auto()
    OPTIMIZED = enum.auto()
```

Now when I run the code I get an `AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'StrEnum'`. I am working with PyCharm, I can see `StrEnum` class is apart of the `enum` library. So, can someone please explain what I am doing wrong, or whats going on here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you're running it with Python 11?

Comment: Could there be a module or package `enum` (file `enum.py`) in your own code?

Comment: Check your Python version.  `StrEnum` wasn't added until 3.11.  You can see your version by invoking `python --version`, or from within Python by looking at `sys.version`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's not it.  It's a version problem.

Comment: @Tom Karzes, you are correct, I thought I was running Python 11, however, I'm actually running 3.10.9. I ran this on a machine that had Python 11 and it works as expected. Thank you for help!

Comment: I found my way here with a similar problem. In my case, the error would occur during static analysis of my code using `mypy`.  It turned out `mypy` (installed using `homebrew`) was using `python3.10`, even though I also have `python3.11` installed on my machine. So it seems I may need to abandon my use of `enum.StrEnum` until the `homebrew` installation of `mypy` is upgraded to `python3.11` or greater.

Comment: Following up on my comment above, I got it working again by explicitly installing `mypy` into my `python3.11` and explicitly using `python3.11 -m mypy` when I want to use `mypy`.